# IF duplicate cell value found in column then return value

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, countif

I need to track a person in a data sheet to determine from which location to which location the person moved.

If a person appears more then one time in Column J that means the person has changed the location and the location value is in Column L. For this I have the following code:

```
=IF(J18=J19;IF(COUNTIF(J:J;J18)>1; "From "&L18 &" to "& IF(J18=J19;L19;"");"");"")
```

The problem is if the person changes the location more than two times. In Column O to Column AA I have the months of the year which determines the location of the person.

How can I modify this code to do the above:

```
=IF(J18=J19;IF(COUNTIF(J:J;J18)>1; "From "&L18 &" to "& IF(J18=J19;L19;"");"");"")
```

[image: Example]

Comment: @Byron here is the picture [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2cyhsm/8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a *User Defined Function* (aka UDF) to accomplish the task.

```
Function my_Travels(nm As Range, loc As Range, cal As Range)
    Dim n As Long, cnt As Long, v As Long, vLOCs As Variant, vTMPs As Variant
    Dim iLOC As Long, sTMP As String

    my_Travels = vbNullString   '"no travels"
    cnt = Application.CountIf(nm.EntireColumn, nm(1))

    If Application.CountIf(nm, nm(1)) = cnt And cnt > 1 Then
        Set loc = loc.Rows(1).Resize(nm.Rows.Count, loc.Columns.Count)
        Set cal = cal.Rows(1).Resize(nm.Rows.Count, cal.Columns.Count)

        'seed the array
        ReDim vLOCs(1 To cnt, 1 To cnt)
        For v = LBound(vLOCs, 1) To UBound(vLOCs, 1)
            vLOCs(v, 1) = cal.Columns.Count + 1
            vLOCs(v, 2) = cal.Columns.Count + 1
        Next v

        'collect the values into the array
        For n = 1 To nm.Rows.Count
            If nm.Cells(n, 1).Value2 = nm.Cells(1, 1).Value2 Then
                iLOC = Application.Match(1, Application.Index(cal, n, 0), 0)
                For v = LBound(vLOCs, 1) To UBound(vLOCs, 1)
                    If vLOCs(v, 1) = cal.Columns.Count + 1 Then
                        vLOCs(v, 1) = iLOC
                        vLOCs(v, 2) = n
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next v
            End If
        Next n

        'sort the values in the array
        For v = LBound(vLOCs, 1) To (UBound(vLOCs, 1) - 1)
            For n = (v + 1) To UBound(vLOCs, 1)
                If vLOCs(v, 1) > vLOCs(n, 1) Then
                    vTMPs = Array(vLOCs(v, 1), vLOCs(v, 2))
                    vLOCs(v, 1) = vLOCs(n, 1)
                    vLOCs(v, 2) = vLOCs(n, 2)
                    vLOCs(n, 1) = vTMPs(0)
                    vLOCs(n, 2) = vTMPs(1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next n
        Next v

        'concatenate the locations from the array
        For v = LBound(vLOCs) To (UBound(vLOCs) - 1)
            sTMP = sTMP & "From " & loc.Cells(vLOCs(v, 2), 1) & " to " & loc.Cells(vLOCs(v + 1, 2), 1) & "; "
        Next v

        'truncate the string and return it
        sTMP = Left(sTMP, Len(sTMP) - 2)
        my_Travels = sTMP

    End If

End Function
```

The *Locations* and the *Calendar* cells only need to be defined by the first row. Each has its height (i.e. *rows*) redefined to maintain consistency with the list of names.

[image: Concatenate Locations]

In AB2 (as above) the formula is,

```
=my_Travels(J2:J$8, L2, O2:AA2)
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Dear @Jeeped thank you very much! It works great :)
I have two questions:
1. Is this possible to do without VBA?
2. In the Calendar cells the value can be from 0,1 to 1 so is it possible to change the code to "count" all cells greater than 0,1?
Thank you again :)

Comment: 1) Marginally possible but the calculation load would be enormous. Iterating an unknown number of rows to concatenate a string means that you have to 'cover all possibilities'². VBA can define the size of its loops on-the-fly. 2) It sounsd like that would change the original conditions to the point that this is no longer a valid answer. If that is the case, then it should be another question. In short, it is hard to hit a moving target.

Comment: Ok, sounds fair enough. One more thing: Sometimes a person have the same location even if the name appears more than one time. Is it possible to not show in column AB the location if the location is the same in every row where a person’s name appears? Thank you :)

Comment: Anything is possible. It sounds like you might need to remove duplicate data but if the same location is recorded as different dates then that sets up a whole different scenario. Sample data bundled together with expected results is the only way to determine this. Again, you keep changing the conditions of the test.

Comment: FWIW, I found your original question intriguing once you got the parameters of the question defined to some level of clarity, I took it on as an intellectual exercise despite the fact that I do not think anyone would ever have the same question again. While your mind may be racing with new possibilities, the people responding to your inquiries are really quite stoic and expect a finite set of parameters to address. If you do post a new question, provide sufficient data (and expected results) to illustrate the issue. Your own efforts toward finding an answer should be front-and-centre.

Comment: My question was quite complex and my inability to express myself in English made the issue even more complex. Thank you for your contribution to solve my complex issue. Pursuant to your request, I will now create a new question with the last query.