# Return output in separate cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have written this [User Defined Function code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492388/if-duplicate-cell-value-found-in-column-then-return-value/30496510#30496510) with the help of user [@Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped).

I need to change two things in this code:

1. That the output must be returned in the respective cells instead of all output being returned in one cell
2. "From" and "To" output must is returned in separate columns.

**This is the Current output:**
[image]

**Desirable output e.g:**
[image]

I have tried to change this part of the code but without success:

```
'concatenate the locations from the array
    For v = LBound(vLOCs) To (UBound(vLOCs) - 1)
        sTMP = sTMP & "From " & loc.Cells(vLOCs(v, 2), 1) & " to " & loc.Cells(vLOCs(v + 1, 2), 1) & "; "
    Next v

    'truncate the string and return it
    sTMP = Left(sTMP, Len(sTMP) - 2)
    my_Travels = sTMP
```

*The complete code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492388/if-duplicate-cell-value-found-in-column-then-return-value/30496510#30496510)*

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Item #1 isn't possible with a UDF. Among the things which a UDF cannot do is: "Change another cell's value." See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787)

Comment: @barrowc I think you misunderstood my question. I just want that the outputs of the UDF should not be grouped in a single cell but distributed in the respektive cells as shown in the picture no. 2 :)

Comment: Can you try `my_Travels = loc.Cells(vLOCs(v, 2), 1)` and `my_Travels .offset(0, 1) = loc.Cells(vLOCs(v + 1, 2), 1)`

Comment: @AlexP Should I replace `my_Travels = sTMP` with your suggestion? :)

Comment: @AlexP I'm not sure how I should use your suggestions?
_Sorry I am newbie in Excel VBA_ :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't reviewed your full code but something like this may work:

```
For v = LBound(vLOCs) To (UBound(vLOCs) - 1)
my_Travels = Left(Loc.Cells(vLOCs(v, 2), 1), Len(Loc.Cells(vLOCs(v, 2), 1)) - 2)
my_Travels.Offset(0, 1) = Left(Loc.Cells(vLOCs(v + 1, 2), 1), Len(Loc.Cells(vLOCs(v + 1, 2), 1)) - 2)
Next v
```

Assuming `my_Travels` is a cell reference then `offset(0, 1)` simply references the cell in the next column along.

Comment: I use this UDF in Excel for the output: `=my_Travels(J2:J$8, L2, O2:AA2)
`

Comment: I get this error: _Compile error Expected: )_ in line  2 and 3

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118934/excel-vba-same-issue-as-asked-by-another-user) is another question stemming from this answer.

Comment: @alex can you please improve your answer?

Comment: See update...I think this solves the errors...parentheses in correct place now

Comment: Super, no fault with parentheses. But there is no output only `#VALUE!` @AlexP